# Inverse Gaussian maximum likelihood estimation lambda

Tags: calculus, statistics, maximum-likelihood

For a regular IG($\mu$,$\lambda$) with pdf:
   $f(x;\mu,\lambda) = \frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^3}^{1/2}$
$e^{\frac{-\lambda}{2\mu^2}\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{x}}$

Taking the log likelihood to produce

$\frac{n}{2}Ln(\lambda)+ \frac{n}{2}Ln(1/2\pi) + K - \frac{\lambda}{2\mu} \sum_1^n{\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{x_i}}$,
k some term not in $\mu \,or \lambda$

Proceeding to differentiate the one relevant term at the end

I get that $\sum_1^n{\frac{(x_i-mu)^2}{x_i}}$ = 0

If this is correct, how does this imply that $\mu$ = sample mean?

What about the second parameter $\lambda$?
It should reduce to $\lambda hat = \frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n{(\frac{1}{x_i} - \frac{1}{\mu^2})}$

Where $\mu$ is the estimated $\mu$ just shown.

Answer (score 3):

First, I believe your PDF is incorrect:  it should be
$$f_X(x \mid \mu, \lambda) = \left(\frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^3}\right)^{1/2} \exp \left( - \frac{\lambda(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2 x} \right), \quad x > 0.$$  [Source:  Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution)

Using this PDF, a likelihood of a sample from this distribution is $$\mathcal L(\mu, \lambda \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto \lambda^{n/2} \exp \left( - \frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{x_i} \right).$$  The log-likelihood is then $$\ell(\mu, \lambda \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto \frac{n}{2} \log \lambda - \frac{\lambda}{2\mu^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{x_i}.$$  If we are interested in estimating $\mu$ for a known $\lambda$, then this expression is more conveniently written $$\ell(\mu, \lambda \mid \boldsymbol x) \propto \frac{n}{2} \log \lambda - \frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{((x_i/\mu) - 1)^2}{x_i},$$ and the partial derivative with respect to $\mu$ is $$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \mu} \propto \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{x_i}{\mu} - 1\right)\frac{1}{\mu^2}.$$  Thus any extremum occurs at a critical point satisfying $\partial \ell/\partial \mu = 0$, or $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = n\mu,$$ hence $\hat \mu = \bar x$ as claimed.

Comment: Great - was a lot of helped. I got there directly by multiplying out the square in the sum and dividing through. Setting to zero means lambda falls away since it is known and a constant not equal to 0.